# Is there anything in Jewish texts on a third gender or gender deviant persons?

Tags: gender-identity

Are there any stories particularly on those who do not fit into the categories man or woman? Is this considered a sin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are indeed discussions in the Gemara (Talmud) of the *tumtum*, an androgynous, i.e., one with both male and female characteristics. The gemara is not judging whether this is good or bad, but is rather interested to understand how various laws apply to *tumtums*, e.g., can they get married with a male or female?

R Alfred Cohen wrote an [article on this](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/english/journal/cohen-1.htm) in the *Journal of Halacha & Contemporary Society*. See also [here](http://www.daatemet.org/issues.cfm?ISSUE_ID=490) although I cannot vouch for that source.

If you are asking about people who are physiologically male of female but feel different, I am not aware that this has been addressed in classical sources (but would love to be corrected). In general, the Torah isn't concerned and doesn't judge how people **feel** but how they **act**. As such *feeling different* wouldn't be a sin, but actions that run contrary to Torah law would be.

Comment: Note further that "gender" in the Jewish legal system of _Halakha_ is a legal category based on technical physical characteristics (eg. a human with a penis needs to be circumcised and shake the Lulav, among other obligations and exemptions that humans in that category have). It is not, and is not trying to be, a proper analogue of one's gender identity.

Comment: Is there the concept of gender identity separate though? For example, yentl, if yentl was actually transgender?