# Transgender identity and judaism

Tags: theology, homosexuality

Why Hachem create transgender people? Did Hachem make some mistakes? Is there a purpos behind it?
What is it the opinion of the rabbis from the different Jewish religious movements?

Is it considered different from male or female homosexuality?
Is it a sin to be transgender or gay?

Comment: I didn't downvote but could imagine someone didn't like when you asked if it was a mistake to create transgender people...

Comment: related: [“Gay” people in the Torah, Talmud, Kabbalah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68062/11501) and [Is there anything in Jewish texts on a third gender or gender deviant persons?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66591/11501)

Comment: This is too many questions in one. Maybe seperate them?

Comment: In reality, it's the same question. Why?

Comment: I think the "gay" part should be edited out: there are trans people of all orientations so it's a pretty different question and probably makes the overall question too broad.

Comment: create transgender people is not clear for me, you mean androgyn?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: We don't know.  All we know is that Hashem created every person to be unique.  There is no one else like you.  I like to quote Rav Nachman of Breslov, who used to say:

> **הַיּוֹם בּוֹ נוֹלַדְתָּ
>   הוּא הַיּוֹם בּוֹ הֶחְלִיט הקב"ה
>   שֶׁהָעוֹלָם אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְהִתְקַיֵּים בַּלְעֲדֶיךָ**
>
> "The day that you were born is the day God decided the world could not be preserved without you."

It's up to us to find out what our contribution will be.

Comment: Source for "we don't know"? Of course it's hard to prove no authority ever said "I know, it's..." but if someone said that it's unknown then that should be cited.

Comment: It is very beautiful. It's seems written for depressed people

Comment: This subject is actually discussed by Ramban in connection with Yitzchok Avinu and Rivkah. It is also dealt with in Sefer Mayim Rabbim by the Maggid , Yechiel Michal ben Yitzchok of Zlotchov to parshat Toldot. Even though people are born this way, they are required to behave according to their external, physical body. If they are born physically male, that is how they are required by the Creator to live. Part of what they can take comfort from is knowing that Yitzchok Avinu faced the same challenges.